# OAuth2 authentication with an CSRF-Token in Flutter

Tags: cookies, flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, csrf-token

I want to authenticate my flutter app to an REST API with the [Oauth2 package](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) but the REST API ask the CSRF Token in the request.   Here is my code, does someone know how and where I can add this  Token ?

I tried to modify the example of code provide by Oauth2 flutter library, but it doesn't work.

```dart
void Login() async {
  final authorizationEndpoint = Uri.parse(
      "http://ipadress:8000/oauth2/authorization/");

  final username = "user";
  final password = "pass";

  final identifier = "DG9GSrfae8gCzWDJU0jbxQC6DAUsTl8dSBMxwPEz";
  final secret = await getCsrftoken();

  var client = await oauth2.resourceOwnerPasswordGrant(
    authorizationEndpoint, username, password,
    identifier: identifier, secret: secret,);

  var result = await client.read("http://ipadress/api/users/me/");
  print(result);

new File("~/.myapp/credentials.json")
    .writeAsString(client.credentials.toJson());

}

Future<String> getCsrftoken() async {
  var response =
  await http.get(Uri.encodeFull('http://ipadress:8000/login/'));
  var csrftoken =
  response.headers.remove('set-cookie').substring(10, 74); //csrf 64 chars
  return csrftoken;
}
```

$ Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /oauth2/authorization/

$ "POST /oauth2/authorization/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2990

Comment: Have you checked the value of the returned `csrftoken`?

Comment: Yes I check it and it seems correct because I have something like that : OjcUgCeCOYDrSerN55KsM0up8iaS5HPaJ1WLVPobx1R7c0N8RsZl2q9PlLOofwBm

Comment: You might want to check with your backend as to where you have to add the token.

Comment: When I check the backend, the token should be set in the header of the request but I haven't found any method to do that with Oauth2 package..

Comment: In that case what is the `secret`?

Comment: It's the secret code of my client which is not necessary in mycase. So I tried to put my CSRF token on it  but it didn't work.

Comment: Headers are specified as `Map`'s. Any chance you know for what `key` the value has to be passed?

Comment: Here are all the type of value that can be put in my Oauth2 header :               
     `authorizationEndpoint, username, password,
      identifier:  , secret:  ,scopes: ,basicAuth: ,delimiter: ,getParameters: ,httpClient: ,onCredentialsRefreshed: ,`                    and I don't know the `key` value

Comment: I think you should try sending the token in secret with `basicAuth` as false

Comment: @joce have you made any progress in this? Could you share the solution here if you've resolved it?

Comment: was this ever resolved?